# Good Ruby on Rails book for a .Net developer

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails

I'm predominantly a .Net developer but am wanting to look into ruby on rails.

Has anyone else been in this situation? And can they recommend any good books/tutorials/general resources for someone wanting to cross over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this one useful..

Rails for .Net Developers
(Pragmatic Bookshelf)

http://pragprog.com/titles/cerailn/rails-for-net-developers

Answer (score 1):

I was very happy with http://railstutorial.org/book. It's not targeted at .NET developers at all, but overall it was a great way to dive into Rails. What I really liked is it touches all aspects, such as rspec and TDD, using webrat for integration testing, FactoryGirl for factories, etc. You go from absolutely nothing to feeling rather comfortable working within the Rails mindset and community.

It also has the added advantage of being written against Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using ASP.NET MVC, then MVC is the only similarity between Rails and .NET, and the .NET implementation of MVC is awful compared to Rails. I recommend learning Rails from scratch, using the same book the rest of us used, Agile Web Development with Rails, and I strongly suggest that you follow the [Railscasts episodes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/archive), as I find this to be the single most useful Rails resource available once you have learned the basics.